# posts appearing in wordpress media library

Tags: wordpress, search, media

when searching from the media library I am seeing posts and when clicking on them to edit the edit post window opens and not the media edit window. could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: this is not programming related...

Comment: Have you edited your WordPress template. Sounds like you edited some core WP files :(

Comment: Because it's not?  This would be programming related if it was a more general question about wordpress plugins or what not.

Comment: there is a strong possibility a plugin could've caused this, but deactivating all plugins doesn't seem to solve my issue.

Comment: found the problem: wp search mu - when searching from the media library it returns posts as well as media

Answer (score 1):

Anyone using the wp search mu plugin will have the same problem - this info is really useful if one is looking for it. wp search mu has a bug: when searching the media library on post/pages OR the media library itself, the plugin returns post_type: post as media and not only post_type: attachment. solution: disable the plugin and try some other search plugin

Comment: +1 for taking the time to explain what was going wrong with your installation/plugins.